# Click link inside Leaflet Popup and do javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jquery

I have a leaflet map up and running.  It overlays a series of polygons (via GeoJSON) on the map and attaches popups to each polygon. Each of the popups display information about that polygon.

I'd like to have inside the popup a link that, when clicked, runs a javascript function that pulls further smaller polygons via AJAX and shows them.

I can't get the script to catch a click on the link via the normal jQuery/Javascript click events.  Here's what I mean by normal (the following doesn't work):

```
$('a .smallPolygonLink').click(function(e){
  console.log("One of the many Small Polygon Links were Clicked");
});
```

The bindPopup part is as follows.  It runs on each polygon when made and it pops up correctly on clicking on a polygon.  It does show the link, just won't run the above code on click.

```
var popupContent = "Basic Information..." + '<a class="smallPolygonLink" href="#">Click here to see the smaller polygons</a>';
layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/are-duplicate-questions-on-different-se-sites-considered-exact-duplicates.

Comment: So the original cross-posting was not a good idea.  But now that it is done, and both have answers (though the stackoverflow is the actual answer), what's the protocol?  I can't delete this question as it has an answer already.

Comment: Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698975/click-link-inside-leaflet-popup-and-do-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Use `.on()` [instead of .live()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - the element is not onpage when you bind your event handler, so you'll need to bind it dynamically.

```
$('click', 'a .smallPolygonLink', function(e){
  console.log("One of the many Small Polygon Links were Clicked");
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Here's a simpler version in JSFiddle that illustrates. http://jsfiddle.net/2XfVc/

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Calling .bind() on the element when the popup is open works (until it is closed again), but $(document).live() doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Leaflet muffles the events from propagating outside the popup.

One way I have gotten this to work is to trap the content in a jQuery object before binding to the popup.

```
var popupContent = $('<div>').html('<div>Your content</div>');
var marker.bindPopup( popupContent[0] );
```